# Evaluating a function using an array. Error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

Code the causes the error:

```
def ne_LiNbO3(wvl):
    """
    refractive index of pure LiNbO3 from 0.4um to 5um
    reference: https://refractiveindex.info
    wvl = wavelength in microns
    """
    if 0.4 <= wvl <= 5:
        return np.real(
            np.sqrt(
                1
                + 2.9804 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 0.02047)
                + 0.5981 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 0.0666)
                + 8.9543 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 416.08)
            )
        )
    else:
        print("wavelength out of range")
        return np.nan

x = np.linspace(0.4, 5, 100)
no_LiNbO3(x)
```

Python returns an error message that highlights the if statement in the function as the problematic line causing the error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

To resolve this error, I tried np.vectorize() and for loops.  Is there a better way to get around this issue in the context of mathematical functions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Given that `wvl` is an array of values, *what do you think `0.4 <= wvl <= 5` should mean*? What about the error message was unclear? What do you actually want the code to do - for the specific example `x` value, what should the result be, and why?

Comment: I think that you're passing an array to a functino that is expecting a single value--wvl. If it's your intent to pass one element at a time to your function then you'll need to pass one element at a time like : [ne_LiNbO3(i) for i in x].

Comment: If, for example, you wanted the function to accept a single value from the array, and compute the result of applying it to the entire array, *that is exactly what `np.vectorize` is for*; no, there is not a better tool for the job, that is literally why `np.vectorize` is provided. Although the function that you vectorize should probably not `print` anything.

Comment: @Docuemada please don't suggest a list comprehension to process what is known ahead of time to be a Numpy array. This defeats the purpose of using Numpy.

Comment: Anyway: welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I almost closed your question as a duplicate without reading very much, because this is probably the single most common Numpy error message and it has a very limited set of underlying causes. You should try to use the question title to summarize the *actual problem you are trying to solve* - e.g. something vaguely along the lines of "how do I get XYZ result from this code?". Simply reporting the error implies that you have the *other* kind of question, i.e. "why does this error occur with the existing code?".

Comment: Yes, use np functions as suggested by @KarlKnechtel

Comment: `np.greater_equal(wvl, 0.4, where=wvl <= 0.5, out=np.zeros_like(wvl, dtype=bool))`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and advise.  Since I want to compute the result for each value in the input array, I will stick with np.vectorize as Karl suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired subset of `x` with:

```
In [251]: wvl = x[(0.4<=x)&(x<=5)]
In [252]: x.shape
Out[252]: (100,)
In [253]: wvl.shape
Out[253]: (100,)
```

In this it's the whole thing.  The calculation works with the whole `x`, or the `wvl` subset:

```
In [254]: arr =np.real(
     ...:             np.sqrt(
     ...:                 1
     ...:                 + 2.9804 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 0.02047)
     ...:                 + 0.5981 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 0.0666)
     ...:                 + 8.9543 * wvl ** 2 / (wvl ** 2 - 416.08)
     ...:             )
     ...:         )
In [255]: arr
Out[255]: 
array([2.3321198 , 2.28372773, 2.25239717, 2.23054905, 2.21452583,
       2.20232666, 2.19276115, 2.1850767 , 2.1787749 , 2.17351331,
       2.16904941, 2.16520711, 2.16185573, 2.15889652, 2.1562536 ,
       ...

       2.03895049, 2.03656544, 2.03414844, 2.03169918, 2.02921732,
       2.02670254, 2.0241545 , 2.02157287, 2.0189573 , 2.01630744,
       2.01362295, 2.01090345, 2.00814858, 2.00535798, 2.00253127])
```

No need to iterate or "vectorize".  It already works with the whole vector.